# How to refresh particular components on an html page

Tags: java, html

I have an event listener on my html page so that when the value of a component changes, another component will become mandatory. But this only works if you change the value of the component, save the page and reload it

Is there a way to do this without having to save and reload the whole page?

```
@EventListener(targets="licensingStatus", events="onchange")
public void onLicenseStatusChange(IRequestCycle cycle){
....
}
```

**EDIT:**

can a function turn

```
<input jwcid="licensingApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker"/>
```

into this

```
<input jwcid="licensingApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker" validators="validators:maxDateToday"/>
```

Comment: see i am using tapestry and have asked this question using the tapestry but had no replies so was just wondering is this possible with just plain java and html

Comment: Using just HTML and Java it is not possible. Java is going to live on the server and HTML is on the client. HTML itself doesn't have any scripting capability, but if you were to include Javascript you would be able to communicate with the server without a page refresh (AJAX) or use javascript to listen / manipulate the html without bothering the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the component needs to be generated dynamically:

Simplest implementation is using `AJAX`. You can have a listener for any component on your page, and when a change occurs, make an `AJAX` call and make the other component appear.

Else:

If the component already exists and has been made invisible initially and just needs to be made visible then you can have this code

```
document.getElementById('other-component').style.visibility='visible';
```

in your listener.

**EDIT:**

If you just want the new field to be mandatory, you can create a check for it in javascript so that when you enter the submit button or whatever it is, the field is checked whether it is empty or not and if empty gives out a message to the user. Something like this:

```
mystring=document.getElementById('other-component').value; 
if(!mystring.match(/\S/)){
alert ('Empty value is not allowed');
return false;
}else{
 alert ("correct input");
 return true;
}
```

Comment: i have a listener on the component already, im having trouble updating the other component when the event listener is fired

Comment: well if your other component is always there on the page, but hidden then you just need to set its visibility to true in your listener. If the other components value changes according to other previous component, then you need to implement some ajax calls withing your listener.

Comment: would I have to declare the component in Java so to do that? currently i am just using the components id

Comment: what i want to do is make the field mandatory, is there a way to do that?

Comment: it is working but not using tapestry validators which the rest of my components are :/ but ill just have to play around with it... just one more question, is there a way to use a function to add a field to a tag (will edit my answer to show example)

Comment: field to a tag? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: yes it can be. take a look at this http://hamisageek.blogspot.in/2008/09/changing-html-tag-attributes-with.html

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX.  Might be worth looking at a framework like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use Javascript here. You could use [AJAX](http://www.codecoffee.com/articles/ajax.html) and update using getElementById on individual elements when the data is returned.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) make this a lot easier.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  $("#myDiv").html("New data loaded");
  myGlobalMandatoryField = true;
});
```

`myGlobalMandatoryField` can be used in another function to ensure a value is entered in a field.